# How can I automatically “uncheck” my check boxes?

Tags: checkbox

How can I Reset a group of check boxes to ‘unchecked’ (or ‘false’ or 0) in my spreadsheet each week.  Looks like it requires use of a macro or VBA...but I know nothing about such things.

Comment: Please specify where your checkboxes are: Website, application, which environment, which language.
Give an example what you have tried so far and which tutorials you tried out. Give the error messages you got.
And please specify some tags for this question, which help people to find your question.

Comment: Excel spreadsheet.  I used the developer toolbar to add 3 checkboxes.  After a task is performed, manually check each box..  1st time I open the spreadsheet each week, I want to update the dates (I can/did do that) automatically, but then want the 3 checkboxes unchecked (automatically).

Comment: Mike please edit your question. You should make the information as easy accessible as possible, so you have better chances, that people will help you. 
Add example code there, describe, what you have done so far and add a fitting tag to your question. Checkboxes can occur in a lot of languages. Do you seek help for VBA? If yes yu should tag your question with the programming language.